# Finding quadratic twist of elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, extension-field, elliptic-curves

Given a elliptic curve over $F_p$ with the equation $E : y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$, I want to find an isomorphous curve (quadratic twist) which can be written in the form $E': y^2 = x^3 + A'x + B'$ where $A'$ is a given.

Following [Wikipedia's description of quadratic twists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twists_of_curves#Quadratic_twist), this seems to be easy: since $E' : y^2 = x^3 + Ad^3x +Bd^2$ where $d$ is the twisting parameter. Solving $A'=Ad^3$ gives $d = \sqrt[3]{\frac{A'}{A}}$.

Checking with SAGE, however, I get completely wrong results. Given:
$$\begin{align}
p &= \mathrm{0xC302F41D932A36CDA7A3463093D18DB78FCE476DE1A86297}
\\ A &= \mathrm{0x6A91174076B1E0E19C39C031FE8685C1CAE040E5C69A28EF}
\\ B &= \mathrm{0x469A28EF7C28CCA3DC721D044F4496BCCA7EF4146FBF25C9}
\\ d &= 2
\end{align}$$
I would expect
$$A' = Ad^3 = \mathrm{0x487CE98D68E62BD64340E8CDA4EDF73017C8E976AE2FBD1C}$$
However, SAGE says that the twist with $d = 2$ is
$$\begin{align}
A' &= \mathrm{0xBDE1643020DCF116CAC0BA0BFFCC9E119EAABCD9AE2D23B2}
\\ B' &= \mathrm{0x472F7598F817AD1ABF3C4F83B6BE0FEE11D68A776B9C52E1}
\end{align}$$
How is this calculation done?

Answer (score 3):

First, since $d=2$ is a square $\bmod{p}$, you would not get a quadratic twist with that $d$ anyway.

Second, you got the twist formula wrong.
[Wikipedia's twist formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twists_of_curves#Quadratic_twist)
translates to $A' = d^2 A$, $B' = d^3 B$.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539269) for the detailed
transformation.
One nice aspect of this is that you will not need cube roots when given $A'$.

Third, SAGE applies a different transformation from the one on Wikipedia,
apparently:
$$\begin{align}
    d\,y^2 &= x^3 + Ax + B      & x' &= x\,d^3  & y' &= y\,d^5
\\\therefore\quad
    y'^2 &= x'^3 + A' x' + B'   & A' &= A\,d^6  & B' &= B\,d^9
\end{align}$$
So, to get SAGE's result, use Wikipedia's formula with $d^3$ instead of $d$.

Fourth, the [SAGE documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plane_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_field.html#sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.ell_field.EllipticCurve_field.quadratic_twist) says:

> If the base field $F$ is finite, $d$ need not be specified, and the curve
>   returned is the unique curve (up to isomorphism) defined over $F$
>   isomorphic to the original curve over the quadratic extension of $F$
>   but not over $F$ itself.

That is, SAGE can simply choose some nonsquare $d$ itself because you can
transform any nonsquare $d$ to any other nonsquare $d$ by scaling $y$ with a
suitable factor.

Therefore I'd suggest that you simply use `E.quadratic_twist()`
instead of `E.quadratic_twist(d)`.
Or at least make sure that $d$ is a nonsquare.